# How to use user input to reference a dictionary in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner at python programming. I am wondering how I would use users input to reference the "Account number" key then print the correct dictionary for that key.

```
#Dictionary entry for John
print("\n")
key123 = {
    "Account number": "123",
    "First Name": "John",
    "Last Name": "Hutch",
    "Savings Amount": 1964,
    "Checkings Amount": 6437
}

#Dictionary entry for Suzie

key456 = {
    "Account number": "456",
    "First Name": "Suzie",
    "Last Name": "Gonzalez",
    "Savings Amount": 2001,
    "Checkings Amount": 1256
}

#Dictionary entry for Zeke

key789 = {
    "Account number": "789",
    "First Name": "Zeke",
    "Last Name": "Pena",
    "Savings Amount": 1200,
    "Checkings Amount": 2313
}
```

Comment: What hav eyou attempted?

Comment: You should not be creating multiple variables for this. Either use a list of dictionaries and iterate to find the matching item, or creating a dictionary that maps account number to the rest of the details.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by list of dictionaries, would I put all of the keys and values under one dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Each entry against a user seems to be a dictionary. So you can make a list of dictionaries and try filtering using the filter function in python. ( As the key on which you want to filter is the same in all the dictionaries in the list, a simple filter function can give you the desired result)

Let's consider you want to filter on basis of **Account_Number = "456"**

```
user_input = "456"

user_details = [
{
    "Account number": "456",
    "First Name": "Suzie",
    "Last Name": "Gonzalez",
    "Savings Amount": 2001,
    "Checkings Amount": 1256
},
{
    "Account number": "789",
    "First Name": "Zeke",
    "Last Name": "Pena",
    "Savings Amount": 1200,
    "Checkings Amount": 2313
}]

res = list(filter(lambda x: x["Account number"] == user_input, user_details))

print(res)

[{'Account number': '456', 'First Name': 'Suzie', 'Last Name': 'Gonzalez', 'Savings Amount': 2001, 'Checkings Amount': 1256}]
```

If you further want to shorten your results or want to get only a few fields out of the dictionary you can use the map function as below:-

```
mapOutput = list(map(lambda x: [x["First Name"], x["Last Name"]], res))

print(mapOutput)

[['Suzie', 'Gonzalez']]
```

Comment: This helped me a lot thank you, heymar I wast't able to get a user input from your code which was in my original question. I would also give you an upvote but my account is too new.

Comment: Hi Heydar, just for Glow's understanding I demonstrated him with an example and further gave him an insight of how he can use map function to filter out key, value pairs he need. I completely agree you answered to this question first, I am just extending it a bit with examples and map function.

Thanks
please don't downvote my answer

Comment: Glad glow that you were able to resolve it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `list` of `dict`.

```
data = [
{
"Account number": "456",
    "First Name": "Zeke",
    "Last Name": "Pena",
    "Savings Amount": 1200,
    "Checkings Amount": 2313
},
"Account number": "456",
    "First Name": "Suzie",
    "Last Name": "Gonzalez",
    "Savings Amount": 2001,
    "Checkings Amount": 1256
}
]
```

Add all of your data in a list.Then search in it with `filter`.

```
filter(lambda x: x["Account number"] == key_input, data)
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you, but how do I ask the user for input or pull up a prompt for the key and print that part of the dictionary? I know that (print[0]) or (print[1]) will work to print the list but how to I get the dictionary printed using unput from the user. Sorry I know it's a terrible question I am very new at this.

Comment: use `input()` to get input from user.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to use `input()` to get the user input, then scan through the accounts to match the account number

```
accounts = {
    'key123' : {   #Dictionary entry for John
        "Account number": "123",
        "First Name": "John",
        "Last Name": "Hutch",
        "Savings Amount": 1964,
        "Checkings Amount": 6437
        },

    'key456' : {   #Dictionary entry for Suzie
        "Account number": "456",
        "First Name": "Suzie",
        "Last Name": "Gonzalez",
        "Savings Amount": 2001,
        "Checkings Amount": 1256
        },

    'key789' : {   #Dictionary entry for Zeke
        "Account number": "789",
        "First Name": "Zeke",
        "Last Name": "Pena",
        "Savings Amount": 1200,
        "Checkings Amount": 2313
        }
}

inp = input("enter account number: ")
list(filter(lambda x: x["Account number"] == inp, accounts.values()))
```

Output

```
enter account number: 123
[{'Account number': '123',
  'Checkings Amount': 6437,
  'First Name': 'John',
  'Last Name': 'Hutch',
  'Savings Amount': 1964}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a correct answer. I was able to use this code:

```
user_input = input("What is your account number?")
user_details = [
{
    "Account number": "123",
    "First Name": "John",
    "Last Name": "Hutch",
    "Savings Amount": 1964,
    "Checkings Amount": 6437
},
{
    "Account number": "456",
    "First Name": "Suzie",
    "Last Name": "Gonzalez",
    "Savings Amount": 2001,
    "Checkings Amount": 1256
},
{
    "Account number": "789",
    "First Name": "Zeke",
    "Last Name": "Pena",
    "Savings Amount": 1200,
    "Checkings Amount": 2313
}]

res = list(filter(lambda x: x["Account number"] == user_input, user_details))
```